# Skip Row Number when previous Row Number is NULL

Tags: sql-server, row-number

I would like to skip row number when previous row number is NULL
My query is as follows

```
select O.Id as orderItemID,Custom,
    CustomName=(CASE WHEN Custom=1 THEN 'Left' When Custom=2 Then 'Right' Else '' END),
    RowNumber = (CASE WHEN Custom = '2' THEN NULL ELSE Row_Number() OVER(ORDER BY O.ID) END )
    From  dbo.OrderItem O 
    left join SubCategory I On O.ItemId=I.ItemId 
    left join ItemType IT On O.Size=IT.TypeId
    where O.OrderId=@OrderId
order by O.Id
```

My output is

[image]

My desired output

[image]

Can any one help me out please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `ROW_NUMBER()` with `PARTITION BY CASE WHEN Custom = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` to make a separate (hidden) counter for rows where `Custom = 2`:

```sql
SELECT   O.Id as orderItemID
        ,Custom
        ,CustomName =(CASE WHEN Custom=1 THEN 'Left' When Custom=2 Then 'Right' Else '' END)
        ,RowNumber = CASE WHEN Custom = 2 THEN NULL ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CASE WHEN Custom = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ORDER BY O.ID) END
FROM  dbo.OrderItem O 
    LEFT JOIN SubCategory I On O.ItemId=I.ItemId 
    LEFT JOIN ItemType IT On O.Size=IT.TypeId
WHERE O.OrderId=@OrderId
ORDER BY O.Id
```